# Wrapper для структуры in6_addr (с++) на C#

Tags: c#, c++

Кто нибудь сможет подсказать. Дана стандартная структура in6_addr на С++ она выглядит так:
`typedef struct in6_addr {
    union {
        UCHAR       Byte[16];
        USHORT      Word[8];
    } u;
} IN6_ADDR, *PIN6_ADDR, FAR *LPIN6_ADDR;`

Требуется написать её отображение на C# (с использованием небезопасного кода).
Заранее спасибо).

Comment: скорее всего возможность задавать адресс с помощью ushort Вам не нужно, поэтому нужен обычный массив на 16 байт (беззнаковых)

Comment: Если я скормлю функции которая требует на вход данную структуру, стандартный 16 байтовый массив. Она его съест? То есть размер этой структуры ровно 16 байт?

Comment: да, размер этой структуры 16 байт (или 8 двухбайтовых слов). Главное, что бы это был правильный массив (не было паддинга)

Comment: Хм..... То есть "union" по сути две разные интерпретации одного участка памяти? Понял. Спасибо.